# Install Firefox in Docker python image

Tags: docker, firefox, dockerfile

I want to install Firefox in a Python image to be able to run regression test on a web application.

Lets say I have the following image, and I want to install Firefox in it:

```
# Image:
FROM python:3.12-bullseye AS builder

# Update kernel with basic tools:
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
       apt-transport-https \
       build-essential \
       ca-certificates \
       software-properties-common
```

But firefox is not available in this distribution, if I run inside a container the following command:

```
apt-cache search firefox
```

It returns nothing.

I have tried to add the repository:

```
# Add Firefox:
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
RUN apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories && apt-get install -y firefox
```

But then I have dependency conflicts:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.31-13+deb11u8 is to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 13.1) but 10.2.1-6 is to be installed
           Depends: libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.8.7) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: xul-ext-ubufox but it is not installable
           Recommends: libcanberra0 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libdbusmenu-glib4 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I properly install Firefox in `python:3.12-bullseye` image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [firefox-esr](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firefox-esr) package in the standard repos, if you're OK with a bit outdated version of the browser.

```
FROM python:3.12-bullseye
RUN apt update && apt install firefox-esr
```